# Investment modeling

Tags: exponential-function, finance, mathematical-modeling

Exponential growth of a capital is given by the expression
$$C(t)=C_0(1+r)^t$$

A typical shape of investments is initially decreasing and gradually becoming exponential later on. This behavior can be modeled by generalizing the hyperbolic cosinus

$$\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}$$

into

$$C(t) = C_1 (1+r_1)^t + C_2 (1-r_2)^t$$

with positive $r_1, r_2$ and $r_2<1$.

At time $t=0$, the initial capital is the sum of the growing component $C_1$ and the decaying one $C_2$, $C(0)=C_1+C_2$

When the minimum of the function is at $t_{min}>0$, we can estimate the time when the capital is recovered, some $t>t_{min}$ where $C(t)=C(0)$.

> Does this two component function have a name and derivation in finance?

Comment: I don't know of a name but its just the sum of two compound interest processes so I'd be surprised if this had a name for its own.

Comment: For the derivation part, the formula matches the solution of a second-order linear differential equation when the characteristic polynomial has two real roots.

Comment: Are you willing to compute $t$ such that $C(t)$ is minimum or the time at which $C(t)=C(0)$ ? It is not clear to me. The first one is simple.

Comment: I am more interested in the time at which $C(t) = C(0)$ and was thinking about an iterative method. But I wondered whether this formula is actually used in finance as a simple model for an investment and where it would come from, because here it is "obtained" with little justification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $$C(t) = C_1 (1+r_1)^t + C_2 (1-r_2)^t$$ is minimum at
$$t_*=-\frac{\log \left(-\frac{C_1 \log (1+r_1)}{C_2 \log (1-r_2)}\right)}{\log
   (1+r_1)-\log (1-r_2)}$$

Now, if you want to *approximate* $t$ such that $C(t)=\text{something}$, you can use a series expansion around $t_*$ which will be
$$C(t)=C(t_*)+ \frac 12 C''(t_*) (t-t_*)^2 + O\left((t-t_*)^3 \right)$$ with
$$C''(t)=C_1 \log^2 (1+r_1)\,(1+r_1)^t+C_2 \log^2 (1-r_2)\,(1-r_2)^t \quad > ~~0$$ But all of that requires that $C(t_*) <0$.